# Trigger #states via custom jQuery

Tags: javascript

I have a form using #states which is great, but once a hidden field is made visible I would like the user to be able to hide it again by clicking a close button, rather than deselecting the original checkbox - hopefully by triggering the original states function. Is there a Drupal way to do this?

Comment: u can use jquery to fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

If "#edit-radiobutton" should launch the state, just do:

```
jQuery('#edit-radiobutton').click().trigger('change');
```

Comment: Might be a jQuery version thing, I needed `jQuery('#edit-radiobutton').click().change();`

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you unhide a field using #states, and want the end user to hide it again.
If thats the case, there is no way you can do this in drupal.
You can use Jquery to do so, use .hide() function to hide that particular div.